# Gack ID - 434450130 during OAuth access token request

Tags: oauth2, gack

I am getting an Internal Server Error with Gack ID 434450130 and Error ID 1693017628-12663. This only happens for two very specific Salesforce orgs during the OAuth2 process when we hit `/services/oauth2/token`. Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the real reason behind GACK can be confirmed only by salesforce. Create a ticket with salesforce support and they should be able to tell you the reason.

Comment: Probably single sign on is enabled and Admin has disabled signing on via other methods

Comment: RedDevil, unfortunately I am on a Standard account so cannot create a support case. The docs suggested posting the IDs here.

Comment: Pranay, how do I check if sign on via OAuth is disabled? I do have admin access to the orgs in question.

Comment: Solved by "uninstalling" the app from Salesforce and then reauthenticating.